# Remote admin of glassfish does not work

Tags: java, glassfish, glassfish-3, remote-administration

I have a server on remote where i am logged by ssh. I have unzip it the glassfish v 3.1.2 and follow the steps http://bbissett.blogspot.com.es/2012/01/asadmin-with-remote-glassfish.html until the part where enters in the link of admin(port 4848) There I am redirect by the browser to the web where the login loader (ip-glassfish-installed:4848) starts spinning and nothing happens.

The log I got in the server is "User [] from host localhost does not have administration access|#]" But I have changed the admin password and login with it. So I dont understand in first instance why I got the user empty. Also, although I think is not related, says that the certificate has expired.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable remote adminstration. Here are couple of other useful links that provide help in that direction:

- http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/enabling_remote_administration_for_glassfish
- https://blogs.oracle.com/quinn/entry/securing_adminstration_in_glassfish_server1

Comment: thanks Arun, but as you can see on the link i posted i also did that, the problem is that the user I logged in by ssh did not have the right permission to execute the domain, even if i use sudo su. If I enter in the remote machine with the root user everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the user I logged in the remote machine by ssh did not have the right permission to execute the domain, even after doing "sudo su". If I enter in the remote machine with the root user everything works fine, or using "sudo su -" after login with the normal user.